# Hadoop: Processing logic close to data, rather than data close to processing logic explanation

Tags: hadoop, distributed-system

I was having a read on an [IBM article related to Hadoop](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-introhdfs/) and one of the points listed was

Hadoop Distributed File System has many goals. Here are some of the most notable:

> Processing logic close to the data, rather than the data close to the processing logic

It sounds to me like a play of words. Is there any difference between processing logic close to the data and data close to processing logic.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a difference.

Taking the processing close to the data means running the business logic on the server where the data actually sits.

Compare this to bringing data close to the processing, where maybe you query a database, and join it with some other system. In this case, the data is sent over the network.

It's argued that sending code and libraries will be significantly less overhead in network transfer than pulling out gigabytes and terabytes worth of data.

In Hadoop2, this is handled by YARN, on which the mapreduce, or Spark, etc. processes run from process containers in parallel to the datanode process.